# Binding of a Collection nested inside a Model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone.js-collections

I have this model structure in my mind:

```
var app = app || {};

// Caratteristica
app.Attribute = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {     
        name: '',
        selected: false 
    }
});

app.Attributes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Attribute
});

// Tipo Caratteristica
app.AttributeCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {     
        name: '', 
        attributes: new app.Attributes() 
    }
});

app.AttributeCategories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.AttributeCategory, 
    url: '/ajax/attributes.cfm'
});
```

My API in *'/ajax/attributes.cfm'* will give me a response like that:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Type1",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Attribute1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Attribute2"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Attribute3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Type2",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": "1234",
                "name": "Attribute1234"
            },
            {
                "id": "2567",
                "name": "Attribute2567"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My question is: will this json data be parsed correctly into my nested data structure?
I mean I want to end up having two *app.AttributeCategory* items in my *app.AttributeCategories* collection. Each of these two items must then have its *attributes* property filled with the corresponding *app.Attributes* collection.

If the answer was NO, how would I override the *parse()* function for achieving that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the collection inside an initialize method in your AttributeCategory model, like this:

```
app.AttributeCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({

    ...

    initialize: function () {
      this.set('attributes', new app.Attributes(this.get('attributes')));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
// Tipo Caratteristica
app.AttributeCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {     
        name: ''
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.set('attributes', new app.Attributes(options.attributes));
        Backbone.Model.prototype.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

But better use RationalModel for set up relations betweens models